# How to configure React Navigation with BottomTabNav & MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

***Desired Outcome***

I'm creating an app that uses a BottomTabNav as the primary navigation between screens.

I also want to include three buttons in a bar at the top of most screens.  The left most button should open a drawer from the left side of the screen and the other two buttons will navigate to specific screens.

What is the best way to handle the navigation for the top bar as specified?

***What I've tried***

I've created a bottomTabNav but I'm not sure the best way to create the top navigation bar since I don't know how to use both on the same screen in React Navigation 3.0 and because I need to have one of the buttons open a drawer from the left side of the screen.

***BottomTabNav***

```
const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Instant: {
      screen: Instant
    },
    Profile:{
      screen: Profile
    },
    Log: {
      screen: StartCompConfirm
    },
    InstantCompScreen: {
      screen: InstantCompScreen
    },
    Stats: {
      screen: StatsComponent
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: CustomTabNav,
    initialRouteName: "Home",  
  });
```

***Authentication Switch Navigator***

```
const AuthStack = createSwitchNavigator({ //this was a stack navigator in the example but that was causing state issue in guesture file so I switched to Switch Navigator
  Signup: {
    screen: SignupScreen
  },
  SignupAddFriends: {
    screen: SignupAddFriends
  },
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  ForgotPassword: {
    screen: ForgotPasswordScreen
  },
});
```

***AppContainer***

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: BottomTabNav,
    Auth: AuthStack,
    TopNav: TopTabNav //TODO: I need to figure out how to nest the top navigator inside of the bottom navigator I think
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading' 
  }
));

export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: Just to be clear. You want a topBar with buttons in some of the screens which happen to be in your BottomTabNavigator?

Comment: That’s correct! I also want to include it in some screens that aren’t included in the bottomTabNav